# get uvw coordinates from pixel coordinates for ray-tracing

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, vector-graphics, raytracing

I'm trying to implement a simple ray-tracing algorithm
so the first step is to convert pixel coordinates into uvw coordinates system
iam using those two equations that i found in a book
[image]

where l,r,b,t are the view frustum points , (i,j) are the pixel indexes  , (nx,ny) are the scene width and height

then to calculate canonical coordinate i use

[image]

i want to understand the previous equations and why they give uwv coordinates for perspective projection not for orthogonal projection (when i use orthogonal projection the equation still gives the result as if perspective projection is used)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume your camera is some sort of a pyramid. It has a bottom face which I'll refer to as the "camera screen", and the height of the pyramid, also known as the focal length, will be marked as F (or in your equations, Ws).

```
         T(op)
       *---------*
       |\       /|
       | \     / |
       |  \   /  |
       |   \ /   |
L(eft) |    *E(ye| R(ight)
       |   / \   |
       |  /   \  |
       | /     \ |
       |/       \|
       *---------*
         B(ottom)
```

Let's assume `j` goes from the bottom to the top (from `-Ny/2` to `+Ny/2` in steps of `1/Ny`), and `i` goes from left to right (from `-Nx/2` to `+Nx/2` in steps of `1/Nx`). Note that if Ny is even, j goes up to `Nx/2-1` (and similar when `Nx` is even).

As you go from bottom to top in the image, **on the screen**, you move from the `B` value to the `T` value. At the fraction `d` (between 0=bottom and 1=top) of your way from bottom to top, your height is

```
Vs = T + (B-T) * d
```

A bit of messing around shows that the fraction `d` is actually:

```
d = (j + 0.5) / Ny
```

So:

```
Vs = T + (B-T) * (j + 0.5) / Ny
```

And similarly:

```
Us = L + (R-L) * (i + 0.5) / Nx
```

Now, let's denote `U` as the vector going from left to right, `V` from bottom to top, 'W' going from the eye forward. All these vectors are normalized.

Now, assume the eye is located directly above `(0,0)` where that is exactly above the center of the rectangular face of the pyramid.

To go from the eye directly to `(0,0)` you would go:

```
Ws * W
```

And then to go from that point to another point on the screen at indexes `(i,j)` you would go:

```
Us * U + Vs * V
```

You will be able to see that `Us = 0` for `i = 0` and `Vs = 0` for `j = 0` (since `B = -T` and `L = -R`, as the eye is directly above the center of the rectangle).

And finally, if we compose it together, a point on the screen at indexes `(i,j)` is

```
S = E + Us * U + Vs * V + Ws * W
```

Enjoy!

Comment: I fixed a flipped bottom and top in my explanation. The equations were right though. So if something didn't make sense somewhere, try re-reading. Glad to be helpful :)